# Getting Undefined values even with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, undefined

I pushed values into an array inside of a forEach loop. When I call the array outside of the loop, I get these values:

d.data:

```
[{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }]
[{sdfg: '123', yo: 'ghj', fgh: '345' }]
[{gd: '123', asd: '123', bonjour: 'yui' }]
[{hello: '123', asd: '567', fgh: '345' }]
```

forEach Loop:

```
let str_arr = [];
d.data.forEach(recs => {
  each_keys = Object.keys(recs);
  each_vals = Object.values(recs);
  each_vals.forEach(k => {
    if (typeof k == 'string') {
        find_key = Object.keys(recs).find(key => recs[key] === k);
        str_arr.push(find_key);
    } 
   });
});
```

str_arr:

```
["hello", "hello", "hello"]
["yo", "yo", "yo"]
["bonjour", "bonjour", "bonjour"]
[]
```

`console.log(typeof str_arr[0] + ' = ' + str_arr[0]`

Result:

```
string = hello
string = yo
string = bonjour
undefined = undefined
```

I want to push all the str_arr[0] inside one array so I do this?

```
let string_array = [];
if (str_arr[0] !== undefined) {
    string_array.push(str_arr[0]);
}
console.log(string_array);
```

My result is:

```
hello
yo
string
     (empty)
```

Why am I still getting the undefined value in my results?

Comment: Can you share the `array`'s content?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal, are you talking about str_arr?

Comment: @noob yeah that one

Comment: I think you need to show the whole code example for this to make sense.

Comment: Can you post more code that shows the whole process, including the for loop?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal, I added it

Comment: I agree you need to post an example that can be executed. But as an aside, you might want to consider using `.filter()`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter rather than looping and pushing as you are doing.

Comment: @noob what's the content of `str_arr`? as others mentioned we need more context

Comment: what exactly is it are you trying to achieve here? Because even your second result seems incorrect. You are showing "string" which infact isn't part of any of the values available in any of those arrays

Comment: I have added my loop

Comment: @noob also `d.data.forEach(recs => {....` note `d` is `undefined`

Comment: @ManuelAbascal No, if he managed to get data inside str_arr, then d.data is defined.

Comment: @MosiaThabo the OP edited his answer to removing `d`, but again we won't be to assist if we don't know the content of `data`

Comment: It is d.data and that is defined. I can add a sample of that too

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Where is `d` defined?

Answer (score 1):

```js
input_arr = [
  ["hello", "hello", "hello"],
  ["yo", "yo", "yo"],
  ["bonjour", "bonjour", "bonjour"],
  []
];
let output_array = [];
input_arr.forEach(element => {
  if (element[0] !== undefined) {
    output_array.push(element[0]);
  }
});
console.log(output_array);
console.log(input_arr[3][0] !== undefined); // works as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Results from the forEach loop
var str_arr = 
[
  ["hello", "hello", "hello"], 
  ["yo", "yo", "yo"],
  ["bonjour", "bonjour", "bonjour"],
  []
];

let string_array = []; 

str_arr.forEach(
  function (item_arr)
  {
    if (item_arr[0] !== undefined || item_arr)
    {
      string_array.push(item_arr[0]);
    }
  }
);

// Here's your answer
console.log(string_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your post, you state:

> d.data:

```
[{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }]
[{sdfg: '123', yo: 'ghj', fgh: '345' }]
[{gd: '123', asd: '123', bonjour: 'yui' }]
[{hello: '123', asd: '567', fgh: '345' }]
```

This does not make sense as this would be 4 unique arrays, making `data` an Array of Arrays (with Objects in them). This would be represented llike follows.

```
d.data = [
  [{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }],
  [{sdfg: '123', yo: 'ghj', fgh: '345' }],
  [{gd: '123', asd: '123', bonjour: 'yui' }],
  [{hello: '123', asd: '567', fgh: '345' }]
];
```

Or should it be an Array of Objects, represented like:

```
d.data = [
  {hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' },
  {sdfg: '123', yo: 'ghj', fgh: '345' },
  {gd: '123', asd: '123', bonjour: 'yui' },
  {hello: '123', asd: '567', fgh: '345' }
];
```

I also cannot determine if you mean to have the strings that contain Numbers be Integers or Strings in the Objects. You seem to be looking for Strings in your `if()`, yet the way they are stored, they are all Strings.

Assuming the latter, and that they might need to be considered Numbers and not Strings, I would suggest using `$.each()` and `parseInt()`.

```js
$(function() {
  var d = {
    data: [{
        hello: 'abc',
        asd: '123',
        fgh: '345'
      },
      {
        sdfg: '123',
        yo: 'ghj',
        fgh: '345'
      },
      {
        gd: '123',
        asd: '123',
        bonjour: 'yui'
      },
      {
        hello: '123',
        asd: '567',
        fgh: '345'
      }
    ]
  };
  var str_arr = [];

  $.each(d.data, function(i, el) {
    console.log(i, el);
    $.each(el, function(k, v) {
      console.log(k + ": " + v);
      if (!(parseInt(v))) {
        console.log("Found String: " + k);
        str_arr.push(k);
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(str_arr.join(", "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here we iterate each element (`i` = Array Index, `el` = Array Element) in the Array. As the element is an Object, we then nest a second loop to iterate the Object (`k` = Object Keys, `v` = Object Values).

Now we can test the Value and store the Key in the `str_arr` if it meets the conditions. I think this is what you were trying to do with your code. Really not sure.

You could also look at using `.map()` or `.filter()` they would both be able to do this too. Perhaps with fewer lines.